# Thinning and burn-in in Metropolis-Hastings algorithm

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I have written a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm manually in Julia language for a customized distribution, and i want now to know how can i perform the thinning and the burn-in to increase the efficiency of the algorithm, i would appreciate if i've been given a simple example to understand more.

Comment: I don’t think either will increase efficiency?

Comment: but they will make the code more stable that's why i wanna know how to do it